# Command Parameter with RelayCommand

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, command, .net-4.5

I'm using a version of the common RelayCommand class and trying to pass a command parameter but not having success. I get the following error:

`Error 29 Method 'Private Sub KeyPadPressExecute(param As Object)' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Sub Action()'.`

I've looked at the many examples of using parameters with commands, but I can't make sense out of them. I don't understand where I'm supposed to get the parameter from that will be passed on to `KeyPadPressExecute()`.

Here's the relevant code:

```vb
Private Sub KeyPadPressExecute(param As Object)
    Debug.Print(param.ToString)
End Sub
Private Function CanKeyPadPressExecute() As Boolean
    Return True
End Function
Public ReadOnly Property KeyPadPress() As ICommand
    Get 'Error occurs on next line
        Return New RelayCommand(AddressOf KeyPadPressExecute, AddressOf CanKeyPadPressExecute)
    End Get
End Property
```

What my XAML looks like:

```xml
<Button Command="{Binding KeyPadPress}" CommandParameter="1" Width="84"></Button>
```

I'm using VS 2012 and targeting .NET 4.5.

**Note:** My original post said I was using MicroMVVM. Closer inspect of the project indicates that the assembly named MicroMVVM is not related to the MicroMVVM framework hosted at codeplex. This project was started by someone else, thus the confusion.

Comment: I changed my code to `Return New RelayCommand(Of String)(AddressOf KeyPadPressExecute...` and now it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a `RelayCommand` implementation seen at [GitHub](https://github.com/ucabpa3/WordCloud/blob/master/MicroMvvm/RelayCommand.cs), one can tell that the class effectively hides and swallows the command parameter. Perhaps you should try to use the generic version of the class instead: `RelayCommand(Of T)`. The run-time exception is pretty clear: there's a mismatch between the **MicroMVVM** class's constructor, taking only a *blunt* `Sub Action()` delegate; and your command's execute handler, taking an `object` argument.

**NB**: Please forgive my bad `VB`, it's not my *mother tongue*.

*Update*: I see that MicroMVVM is hosted at CodePlex, but there's no `RelayCommand` class in there (apparently replaced by the smarter `DelegateCommand` class). The link to the probably unrelated project at GitHub still serves its purpose as an example and source of information. Comments are welcome.